# Problems with STUFF and XML PATH - Researched a lot but no luck

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've looked up many questions and answer on here about XML PATH and STUFF but I cannot get it working for my query.  I know it's user error but I can't figure it out.  Any help appreciated.

Here's my sample query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     map.Name
    ,loc.MainAddress
    ,loc.MainCity
    ,loc.MainStateProvince_MisStateProvID
    ,loc.MainZipPostal
FROM                meditech_livefdb.dbo.MisLoc_Main             loc
    LEFT OUTER JOIN meditech_livefdb.dbo.MisNomenclatureMap_Main map ON (loc.SourceID = map.SourceID AND loc.NomenclatureMap = map.MisNomenclatureMapID)
WHERE loc.MainAddress = '123 Main Street'
```

`map.Name` lists services offered at each address location.  Most locations have multiple services offered.  I'd like a distinct listing of address locations with a combined field showing all services offered at that location.  I've tried the below and it doesn't work at all.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     loc.MainAddress
    ,loc.MainCity
    ,loc.MainStateProvince_MisStateProvID
    ,loc.MainZipPostal
    ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + map.Name FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Services
FROM                meditech_livefdb.dbo.MisLoc_Main             loc
    LEFT OUTER JOIN meditech_livefdb.dbo.MisNomenclatureMap_Main map ON (loc.SourceID = map.SourceID AND loc.NomenclatureMap = map.MisNomenclatureMapID)
WHERE loc.MainAddress = '123 Main Street'
```

This just gives me the same as the first query.  See what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try referencing the map table separately in your stuff clause (replace map.ID with whatever your unique id field is called):

```
STUFF((SELECT ',' + map2.Name
        FROM meditech_livefdb.dbo.MisNomenclatureMap_Main map2
        WHERE map.ID = map2.ID FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS Services
```

Comment: That's not working either.  Kept the same code as above and added: STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Name
        FROM meditech_livefdb.dbo.MisNomenclatureMap_Main
        WHERE map.MisNomenclatureMapID = MisNomenclatureMapID
            AND map.SourceID = SourceID
            AND map.Active = Active
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS Services2.  Same results??

Comment: I'm not sure, if you could provide some sample data I could troubleshoot more